# How to tell when a user leaves the site with Blazor Server Side

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Blazor server side is built on signalr, so I would assume that it knows when a user leaves the website (closes the connection). Is there any event raised that I can use to log this? Or any other way really!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this service can help you...

```
public class CircuitHandlerService : CircuitHandler 
    {
        public ConcurrentDictionary<string, Circuit> Circuits { get; set; }
        public event EventHandler CircuitsChanged;

        protected virtual void OnCircuitsChanged()
        => CircuitsChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        public CircuitHandlerService()
        {
            Circuits = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Circuit>();
        }

        public override Task OnCircuitOpenedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Circuits[circuit.Id] = circuit;
            OnCircuitsChanged();
            return base.OnCircuitOpenedAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task OnCircuitClosedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnCircuitClosedAsync");
            Circuit circuitRemoved;
            Circuits.TryRemove(circuit.Id, out circuitRemoved);
            OnCircuitsChanged();
            return base.OnCircuitClosedAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task OnConnectionDownAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnConnectionDownAsync");
            return base.OnConnectionDownAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task OnConnectionUpAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.OnConnectionUpAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
        }
               
    }
```

Testing

### Index.razor

```
@page "/"

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits
@using BlazorCircuitHandler.Services

@inject CircuitHandler circuitHandler
@implements IDisposable



<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<p>
    Number of Circuits: @((circuitHandler as <BlazorCircuitHandler is a name space in my app>.Services.CircuitHandlerService).Circuits.Count)
    <ul>
        @foreach (var circuit in (circuitHandler as BlazorCircuitHandler.Services.CircuitHandlerService).Circuits)
        {
            <li>@circuit.Key</li>
        }
    </ul>
</p>

@code {

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        (circuitHandler as CircuitHandlerService).CircuitsChanged += HandleCircuitsChanged;
        
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        
        (circuitHandler as CircuitHandlerService).CircuitsChanged -= HandleCircuitsChanged;
       
    }

    public void HandleCircuitsChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // notify the UI that the state has changed
          InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
    }
}
```

### Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();

            services.AddSingleton<CircuitHandler>(new CircuitHandlerService());
        }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks! It's a great start for me. Do you have any idea how I can now reference the circuit id from within a circuit? (So when a user logs on I can associate their username with the circuit id)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot your comment... I guess you mean how to reference the circuit id from within the circuit handler, right ? Generally speaking, you could use the username as the key in ConcurrentDictionary<string, Circuit> Circuits, instead of circuit.Id, thus associating a Circuit object with a user name. You could inject the AuthenticationStateProvider into the CircuitHandler, and extract the username, but the issue is that AuthenticationStateProvider  is scoped while CircuitHandler is Singleton. So you can't use both. You may make the CircuitHandler service scoped,

Comment: but then it becomes useless as it only reference to the current app. 
What you can try to do is extract the username from the startup class via HttpContext, and then pass it to the constructor of the CircuitHandler service. I think this is doable. You should also take into account the case when the user is not authenticated, and thus the parameter you're going to pass to  CircuitHandler is going to be null. Note that a user can be associated with multiple circuits if he opens new instances of the app.

Comment: I would suggest you to search for material related to the Circuit object. I'm not much familiar with this advance stuff, and it is poorly covered by the docs. Good luck

Answer (score 4):

I would do and have done the following.

Create an interface and an implementation of that interface that fits your scenario with the following signature. This will be your central service that keeps track of your users online status.

```
public interface IUserOnlineService
{
    void Connect(string circuitId, User user);
    void DisConnect(string circuitId);
}
```

Inject your implementation of the interface in your startup as a singleton.

Then create a custom class that derives from CircuitHandler. It should use an instance of your previously created IUserOnlineService.

```
public class CircuitHandlerService : CircuitHandler
{
    public string CircuitId { get; set; }

    IUserOnlineService useronlineservice;
    public CircuitHandlerService(IUserOnlineService useronlineservice)
    {
        this.useronlineservice = useronlineservice;
    }

    public override Task OnCircuitOpenedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        CircuitId = circuit.Id;
        return base.OnCircuitOpenedAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override Task OnCircuitClosedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        useronlineservice.DisConnect(circuit.Id);
        return base.OnCircuitClosedAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Add this service as a scoped service in your startup. This way there will be an instance pr connection.

```
services.AddScoped<CircuitHandler>((sp) => new CircuitHandlerService(sp.GetRequiredService<IUserOnlineService>()));
```

Now inject your CircuitHandler and IUserOnLineservice whereever you have your login-logic and then after user-authentication, use the CircuitId property on the Circuithandler which will hold the Id of your current connection and call Connect() on the IUserOnlineService interface. Disconnect is handled in the CircuitHandler as we here only need (and have) the circuit-Id.

Comment: I implemented a solution based on this post.  It looks to be working well.  My key takeaway was to make the CircuitHandlerService scoped instead of singleton.  That allows for correlation between user data and the Circuit Id.  Thanks Jesper!

Comment: Thanks, this works really well as a way to track user activity

Comment: I'm doing this implementation, but when I inject 'CircuitHandlerService' in MainLayout, the CircuitId is null

Answer (score 2):

As Enet already commented is that if you want to inject the AuthenticationStateProvider in the [TrackingCircuitHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/advanced-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0), the TrackingCircuitHandler needs also to be scoped as the AuthenticationStateProvider.

If you want to track the usernames in your application, you can use the [In-memory state container service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server#in-memory-state-container-service-server) as a singleton and inject this in the TrackingCircuitHandler.

If you just want to log when a user leaves the website, you can skip the IUsersStateContainer and just inject the Logger.

First create a in-memory 'UsersStateContainer':

```
 public class UsersStateContainer : IUsersStateContainer
    {
        public ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> UsersByConnectionId { get; set; } =
            new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

        public event Action OnChange;
        public void Update(string connectionId, string name)
        {
            UsersByConnectionId.AddOrUpdate(connectionId, name, (key, oldValue) => name );
            NotifyStateChanged();
        }
        public void Remove(string connectionId)
        {
            UsersByConnectionId.TryRemove(connectionId, out var _);
            NotifyStateChanged();
        }
        private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
    }
```

Add this service as a scoped service in your startup:

```
services.AddSingleton<IUsersStateContainer, UsersStateContainer>();
```

The TrackingCircuitHandler uses the IUserStateContainer:

```
 public class TrackingCircuitHandler: CircuitHandler
    {

        private IUsersStateContainer _usersStateContainer;
        private AuthenticationStateProvider  _authenticationStateProvider;

        public TrackingCircuitHandler(IUsersStateContainer usersStateContainer, AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
        {
            _usersStateContainer = usersStateContainer;
            _authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
        }

        public override async Task OnConnectionUpAsync(Circuit circuit, 
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var state =  await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            _usersStateContainer.Update(circuit.Id, state.User.Identity.Name);

            return ;
        }

        public override Task OnConnectionDownAsync(Circuit circuit, 
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _usersStateContainer.Remove(circuit.Id);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

       
    }
```

Add this as scoped service to startup.cs:

```
services.AddScoped<CircuitHandler, TrackingCircuitHandler>();
```

To show the active users on a blazor page:

```
@page "/UserStatePage"
@inject IUsersStateContainer UsersStateContainer
@implements IDisposable

 <h2>Connected users</h2>
        <ul>
            @foreach (var user in UsersStateContainer.UsersByConnectionId)
            {
                <li>@user.Key - @user.Value</li>
            }

        </ul>
@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        UsersStateContainer.OnChange += OnMyChangeHandler;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        UsersStateContainer.OnChange -= OnMyChangeHandler;
    }
    
    private async void OnMyChangeHandler()
    {
    // invoke on ui thread
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does the IUsersStateContainer come from?

Answer (score 1):

In your app, there is probably a class that derives from Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub. If not you can create one. Then in this class

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
}
```

fires when the user disconnects. The Context property of the Hub has information about the user (at least the connection id).

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't give access to the blazor hub, so I can't use it to track the state of the blazor circuits