# Get a list of all connected users to a Blazor application

Tags: c#, blazor, signalr, blazor-server-side

So for my blazor application is currently in production.

I do need to release new versions at some points.
I would like to know if at that time anyone is using the application.
For this I could ask everyone (about 20 colleagues) whether anyone is using the application.

I feel like there should be an easier way to do this.
Now I know that a blazor application uses SignalR to perform the communication between server and client and that when I restart the docker container, all connections are reset. So I feel like there should be a way to request from the SignalR Hub whether anyone is connected to the application, but I have not yet found a way.

Does anyone know any way of checking if (and who) is using the application at point x in time?

Comment: Have looked into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62685574/how-to-tell-when-a-user-leaves-the-site-with-blazor-server-side).

Comment: @maciek That indeed looks like what I'm looking for, will have a look in the morning. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easy way is to use Dependency Injection. On Blazor server, [scoped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicedescriptor.scoped?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), almost means ["one instance by connection"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0#service-lifetime):

> The Blazor Server hosting model supports the Scoped lifetime across HTTP requests but not across SignalR connection/circuit messages among components that are loaded on the client. The Razor Pages or MVC portion of the app treats scoped services normally and recreates the services on each HTTP request when navigating among pages or views or from a page or view to a component. Scoped services aren't reconstructed when navigating among components on the client, where the communication to the server takes place over the SignalR connection of the user's circuit, not via HTTP requests. In the following component scenarios on the client, scoped services are reconstructed because a new circuit is created for the user:
>
> - The user closes the browser's window. The user opens a new window and navigates back to the app.
> - The user closes a tab of the app in a browser window. The user opens a new tab and navigates back to the app.
> - The user selects the browser's reload/refresh button.

If it's acceptable for you to regard a lifetime SignalR connection/circuit as a "connected user", the process is quite straightforward. I explain the process step by step:

#### 1 - Creating structs to store list of connected users

Create classes to store `ConnectedUser` data and a `ConnectedUserList`:

```cs
public class ConnectedUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
public class ConnectedUserList
{
    public List<ConnectedUser> Users { get; set; } = new();
}
```

#### 2 - Inject classes with the right scope

On `program.cs` inject both classes on services: `ConnectedUser` (scoped) and `ConnectedUserList` (singleton) that will contain a list of `ConnectedUser`.

```cs
// Program.cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<ConnectedUser>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ConnectedUserList>();
```

#### 3 - Capture connected user and add to global list

On `Shared/MainLayout.razor`, get by injection both objects and add `ConnectedUser` to `ConnectedUserList` (on login process or events, you can update `ConnectedUser.Username` to the logged username)

```cs
@implements IDisposable
@inject ConnectedUser _ConnectedUser
@inject ConnectedUserList _ConnectedUserList

@code {

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
         _ConnectedUserList.Add(_ConnectedUser )
    }

    // Don't forget to remove `ConnectedUser` from 
    // `ConnectedUserList` on dispose.
    public void Dispose()
    {
         _ConnectedUserList.Remove(_ConnectedUser )
    }
```

#### 4 - Show all connected users

At any moment you can get `ConnectedUserList` and check the list. For example `index.razor`:

```
@page "/"

@inject ConnectedUser _ConnectedUser
@inject ConnectedUserList _ConnectedUserList

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

@foreach (var user in _ConnectedUserList.Users)
{
    <p>@user.Name</p>
}
```

#### Notes

- To keep the answer simple, I used a `List` struct to store connected users, but `List` is not thread safe.

Comment: In Blazor Server .net 7, MainLayout.razor is based on LayoutComponentBase which doesn't implement IDisposable - Dispose() 0 CS0115: 'MainLayout.Displse()': no suitable method found to override.  I had hoped this would work instead of a CircuitHandler!

Comment: hi @JClarkCDS, please, follow instructions step by step. Also check `Dispose` name, you wrote `MainLayout.Displse()`. As you say, by default, `MainLayout`doesn't implement IDisposable, but, with posted code, it does (search by `public override void Dispose()` on this answer)

Comment: That was a spelling mistake in my comment.  The error is CS0115: 'MainLayout.Dispose()' with public override void Dispose() having the red underline.  I followed the instructions step by step and get the compile error.  When researching the  CS0115, the only reason I could find was the base component doesn't implement IDisposable.

Comment: @JClarkCDS ok, I understand, I removed `override` can you try again?

Answer (score 0):

The posted code snippet in MainLayout.razor is wrong. It is missing a reference to the Users List in the _ConnectedUsersList service.  Try this instead:

```html
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
             _ConnectedUserList.Users.Add(_ConnectedUser );
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for being a contributor to the Stack Overflow community. As a question and answer site, Stack Overflow works differently than most message boards. As such, **kindly reserve the _Answers_ feature for actual answers, not follow-up questions or comments**.