# Blazor application - conected users

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I've developed a website using Blazor and Identity for user connections.

I would like to know if it's possible to have a list of the current users connected?

I have ever tried with a disposable component but the issue is the "dispose" method was sometimes never called when the window of the navigator was shut down. We also tried to find a solution with SignalR but same issue as previously
Has someone have a solution to list of current users connected ?

Thank You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a list of all connected users to a Blazor application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74548005/get-a-list-of-all-connected-users-to-a-blazor-application)

Comment: I tried this but when a user closes the browser I still see him logged in. Maybe on my test environment it doesn't work if the browser is closed directly.

Comment: Maybe this : [How to tell when a user leaves the site with Blazor Server Side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62742771/2703673)